# How to load data into Django template using render and filter loaded data using AJAX requests?

Tags: django, ajax

I'm loading data into my template using render. The data I'm sending to the template includes objects called `course` and `reviews`. Course has an array of `instructors`, while each review has one `instructor`. I'm listing out all the instructors associated to a course as a button on the template, and I would like to filter reviews based on which instructor button the user clicks.

I'm already sending the data from the server to the template, but I'm thinking I need to use AJAX in this. Any ideas on how to do this and would it be possible to do this without sending another request to the server and utilizing the data that has already been sent to the template?

template

```
{% for instructor in course.instructors %}
<button class="ui button">
{{ instructor }}
</button>
{% endfor %}

{% if reviews %}
  {% for review in reviews %}
    <p>Usefulness: {{ review.usefulness_rating }}</p>
    <p>Difficulty: {{ review.difficulty_rating }}</p>
    <p>Instructor: {{ review.instructor_rating }}</p>
    <p>Comment: {{ review.comment }}</p>
    <p>Instructor: {{ review.instructor }}</p>
    <p>Session: {{ review.taken_season }} {{ review.taken_year }</p>
```

How should I implement the AJAX for this?